# AWS Lex Simple Bot Statement / Intent

Tags: amazon-web-services, bots, amazon-lex

I was hoping to create an intent that only makes a statement to the user. I was thinking I could do this by having some utterances that trigger the intent with no slots, but with a "goodbye message". When I try to do that, when I save the intent, it deletes the goodbye message and reverts it to None. I also picked a "no-op" lambda function to call since it doesn't make sense for what I'm doing.

At this point, I'm not sure about how to do this, but it seems like the claudia-bot-builder has support for something like this, but I can't get it to deploy to my AWS account to see how it might do it.

Does anyone else here have an idea about how to have the bot just give information in response to an utterance instead of starting a dialog to retrieve information?

Comment: what do you mean `just give information in response to an utterance instead of starting a dialog to retrieve information`?

Comment: you can simple return a message from the lambda function when the intent is triggered

Answer (score 0):

You can return simple messages to the user using only Amazon Lex Console without any Lambda Function selected.
Open your Lex Chat Bot in console.aws.amazon.com/lex/home....

1 Click the **"Editor"** Tab.
2 On the left, click on the Intent you want to return a message on.
3 On the right, scroll down to the **"Fulfillment"** section.
4 Click **"Return parameters to client"**
5 In **"Response"** section, type in the message(s) you want to respond with.

[image: Screen Capture walkthrough]

Note: Make sure the section "Lambda initialization and validation" is unchecked so that the intent goes directly to the "Fulfillment" response.